# проверить строку с URL на наличие недопустимых символов

Tags: php

Нужно проверить URL на наличие недопустимых символов в URL.
Проверяю след. способом:

```
    if(!preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z.\-\/:?&=#%_]/', $url))
    {
...
    }
```

Как быть, при использовании кириллических символов и прочих алфавитов?

Comment: Если сам код в UTF-8 вы можете спокойно прямо в регулярку писать кирилицу в виде А-Я, возможно потребуется отдельно добавить букву "Ё". И после закрывающей регулярку `/` надо поставить букву 'u' - флаг использования UTF в выражении

Comment: @Mike, а что насчет IDN и символа "ñ"? Ведь он является допустимым в испанском.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Не знаю. Если бы знал - написал бы ответ. А так только указал возможное направление для решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\W` Не подходит?

> Соотвествует любому нецифробуквенному символу. Равносилен
>   [^A-Za-z0-9_].

Answer (score 0):

Могу только подсказать установить русскую локаль:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
```

сама регулярка должна быть с ключом  \u

```
!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9а-яА-Я.\-\/:?&=#%_]/u', $url)
```